# Regex for names in multiple languages

Tags: regex, encoding, character

I want the user of my chatbot to write his name in the textbox.

**Following types are fine:**

- Latin letters: John
- Every name with non-latin character such as: àâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇß
- German letters: ä,ü,ö,ß Ä, Ü, Ö
- Multiple names such as: Peter-Alexander
- It is ok, if the user puts a dot at the end of his name: John.

**This is not correct:**

- Max!
- Max123
- Max 123
- Max_
- Max!"§$%&/()

This is what I tried:

```
import re

value='John'

if not re.search(r'\d', value) and not re.search(r"[^a-zA-Z.\-\sÜüßäÄöÖ]", value) and not re.search(r"[.-]\Z", value):
  print('name is correct')
else:
  print('name is not correct')
```

Comment: How is `Max` different from `John`? You also want to allow `-` at the end, right? Not only `.`? Is `John-Pete-Alexander` allowed?

Comment: Sorry, my misstake. Of course, there is no difference between Max and John. I removed it!
Yes, John-Pete-Alexander is fine! My plan was actually to allow only a dot ``.`` at the end of the name. However, if you think other signs like ``!?`` should be allowed, I am fine with that

Comment: Ok, see my answer. You may add `?!` of you need in the final  character class, `[!?.-]?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
re.search(r'^[^\W\d_]+(?:-[^\W\d_]+)*\.?$', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z48nv9/5). If you also allow `-` at the end, use

```
re.search(r'^[^\W\d_]+(?:-[^\W\d_]+)*[.-]?$', text)
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z48nv9/4/). Note you may use `re.fullmatch` to ensure full string match, and you do not need anchors then: `re.fullmatch(r'[^\W\d_]+(?:-[^\W\d_]+)*[.-]?', text)`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\W\d_]+` - 1+ Unicode letters
- `(?:-[^\W\d_]+)*` - 0  or more repetitions of `-` and 1+ Unicode letters
- `[.-]?` - an optional `-` or `.`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you very much. This looks great. Just some smaller questions: If I want to accept white space for names like: ``John Hopkins`` where should I put the symbol for white space ``\s`` ?

Comment: @PParker `(?:-[^\W\d_]+)*` => `(?:[-\s][^\W\d_]+)*`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/z48nv9/6).

Comment: Final Question: What is the correct regex for names like: ``Miky D. Moùse`` There is a dot behind the second name!

Comment: @PParker According to your requirements, `Miky D. Moùse` is invalid since it contains whitespace. If it is a new question, please check if it has not been asked before and then post. Maybe you can use `^[^\W\d_](?:\.|[^\W\d_]*)(?:[-\s][^\W\d_](?:\.|[^\W\d_]*))*[.-]?$`, but I am not sure.